# IWebBrowser2 and Chrome Plugin for Internet Explorer

Tags: delphi, internet-explorer-8, windows-shell

I am trying to get access to the IWebBrowser2 object from Internet Explorer 8 with the chrome plugin.  I am able to access it when the chrome plugin isn't installed, but it doesn't work due to the class names etc different.

Without chrome plugin I can use:

```
function GetIEFromHWND(WHandle: HWND; var IE: IWebbrowser2): HRESULT;
var
  hInst: HWND;
  lRes: Cardinal;
  MSG: Integer;
  pDoc: IHTMLDocument2;
  ObjectFromLresult: TObjectFromLresult;
begin
  Result := 0;
  hInst := LoadLibrary('Oleacc.dll');
  @ObjectFromLresult := GetProcAddress(hInst, 'ObjectFromLresult');
  if @ObjectFromLresult <> nil then begin
    try
      MSG := RegisterWindowMessage('WM_HTML_GETOBJECT');
      SendMessageTimeOut(WHandle, MSG, 0, 0, SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 1000, lRes);
      Result := ObjectFromLresult(lRes, IHTMLDocument2, 0, pDoc);
      if Result = S_OK then
        (pDoc.parentWindow as IServiceProvider).QueryService(IWebbrowserApp, IWebbrowser2, IE);
    finally
      FreeLibrary(hInst);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

This doesn't work (I'm presuming) because there's no IHTMLDocument2 interface (using MS Spy++ you can see that the window heirarachy is completely different).

I can access the instance of the "Tab" that I'm after, but ultimately I need to "refresh" that tab with a new URL (which I was going to use IWebBrowser2.Navigate to accomplish).

I've tried importing the type library for Chrome but I can't find anything in there to help either.  So I'm happy to utilise whatever I need to, in order to refresh tab that I have the handle to.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you need to use Chrome Frame I have wrapped the ActiveX control here:
http://www.progdigy.com/?p=116

But I would suggest you to use Delphi Chromium Embedded Instead, you will have more possibilities.
http://code.google.com/p/delphichromiumembedded/

Comment: Surely the question is about a browser hosted in IE rather than hosted in a Delphi app.

Comment: Thanks, but David is correct.  I need to use Chrome in IE, not within a Delphi app/form.  I have had a look at the embedded version to see if it had any code which might have helped but alas it didn't.